# How to put data from database to session dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am pulling data from database and would like to save it into session variables. I would like to name the keys the same that my table cells are named. So for example:
I have a cell named "EMAIL", and I would like to get $_SESSION["EMAIL"]

 
I already have the data from database saved in an array ($data), which has array keys named after the cells, but I would like to move that data to SESSION array, with same keys...

How can I do this dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either do it like this:

```
foreach($myArr as $k=>$v) {
  $_SESSION[$k] = $v;
}
```

Or,

```
$_SESSION['user'] = $myArr;
```

In the first case, you will access email by doing `$_SESSION['EMAIL']`, and in the second case, `$_SESSION['user']['EMAIL']`;

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is

```
$_SESSION = array_merge($_SESSION, $myArr);
```

I'm not sure if this is a good practice though.